# Calendar corrupted in Android

Tags: android, android-calendar

We are adding entries into the Android calendar from within our code.
For some reason the calendar seems to have been corrupted in some way.

We can't delete any event at all - even ones not added from within our code.
If we try to delete one that was added via our code it crashes.

This is the code we use to insert the event. Note that the text is in Hebrew and we are talking about Android 4.1 and up.

```
        // Select which calendar application to use:
    int cal_id = CalendarAppointmentScheduler._calIds[0];

    // Use a ContentValues object to hold the details of the calendar event you wish to set:
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, cal_id);
    cv.put(Events.TITLE, ctx.getString(R.string.add_appointment_to_calendar_title) + " " + ad.doctorName + " (" +
        ad.doctorSpecialty + ")");
    cv.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, ad.address);
    cv.put(Events.DTSTART, startTime);
    cv.put(Events.DTEND, endTime);
    cv.put(Events.ALL_DAY, 0);  // true = 1, false = 0
    cv.put(Events._ID, ad.diaryRecordIndex);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
        cv.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
```

This is the logcat we get:

```
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "350511201315411-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "350511201315451602"
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:378)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at android.database.MatrixCursor.getInt(MatrixCursor.java:247)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at com.android.calendar.EventInfoFragment.initEventCursor(EventInfoFragment.java:1062)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at com.android.calendar.EventInfoFragment.access$700(EventInfoFragment.java:117)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at com.android.calendar.EventInfoFragment$QueryHandler.onQueryComplete(EventInfoFragment.java:469)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at com.android.calendar.AsyncQueryService.handleMessage(AsyncQueryService.java:412)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 16:22:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(25072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main51602"
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:378)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at android.database.MatrixCursor.getInt(MatrixCursor.java:247)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at com.android.calendar.EventInfoFragment.initEventCursor(EventInfoFragment.java:1062)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at com.android.calendar.EventInfoFragment.access$700(EventInfoFragment.java:117)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at com.android.calendar.EventInfoFragment$QueryHandler.onQueryComplete(EventInfoFragment.java:469)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at com.android.calendar.AsyncQueryService.handleMessage(AsyncQueryService.java:412)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-04 16:22:25.975: E/AndroidRuntime(25027):          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 16:22:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(25072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Comment: Obviously, it gives a NumberFormatException. Maybe you are putting something not an integer into an integer column.

Comment: Thing is I have no problem inserting it. It's only when I try to delete or change it that the problems happen.

Comment: can you share your code for adding and deleting part that causes the event, so I can check?

Comment: It's in the question.

Comment: But there is only a ContentValues object with some values, where is the insertion or deletion?

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104817/calendarcontract-events-bad-id-inserted-calendar-corrupted-in-android/