# CalendarContract Events : bad id inserted, Calendar corrupted in Android

Tags: android, android-calendar

I made a mistake on testing insert Events using CalendarContract.

I set my own _ID in a Events insert.

```
values.put(Events._ID, "156498713465");
```

Now, all my new events are created with a bad id (for exemple -535191590).

When I click to the event in the Google Calendar Application, it crash.

I have the same error as this thread : 
[Calendar corrupted in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769952/calendar-corrupted-in-android)

I tried to delete all bad events :

```
activity.getContentResolver().delete(Events.CONTENT_URI, Events._ID + " > ? ", 
new String[] { "10000" });
```

But when a new events are inserted, a bad id is generated.

My question is :
Where can I reset the Events Id sequence ?

Thanks,
Regards

Comment: that's because of the autoincrementing in sqlite. http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the id; the following will do what you want:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put (Events.CALENDAR_ID, Long.toString(newCalendarId));
values.put (Events.DTSTART, dtStart);
values.put (Events.DTEND, dtEnd);
values.put (Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
values.put (Events.TITLE, title);
Uri uri = cr.insert (Events.CONTENT_URI, values); 

// The returned uri will contain the eventId assigned by Events.
```

Comment: My question is : Can I reset sqllite sequence because I made a mistake (set my own id). I don't want to reset my phone.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean.  SQLite is software - nothing to reset.  If you mean reset the data in the Android Calendar, that is possible.

Comment: Assuming that your calendar is synchronized with a cloud database, you can clear the Android data and resynch from the cloud.  Anything added since the last synch will be gone, of course.  Hopefully, your bad data was not synched to the cloud...  To clear the Android data, go to "manage applications", choose Calendar, clear data.  Do the same for Calendar Storage.